# an arduous grep between two lists

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have two different txt file. The first called "all_E3.txt" contains a list of objects (in column) and in this list there are also a lot of duplicated objects. In another file called "UPS.txt" there is a list of objects in column (no duplicates) and for each objects is associated a variable (same row another column and it's a number or "N.A.").

In this file there are also (but not only) objects present in file "all_E3.txt". I would like to obtained another file called "output_UPS.txt" in which there are all the objects present in "ALL_E3.txt" with the corresponding variable as per "UPS.txt" . For example:

- file "all_E3.txt" :

  ```
  AMFR
  AMFR
  AMFR
  ANAPC11
  CRB
  CRB
  TER
  CAM
  DVDE
  ```
- file 2 "UPS.txt"

  ```
  AMFR 0
  REF 1
  SDRF N.A.
  BHU 3 
  ANAPC11 2
  CRB 2
  YUT 1
  TER 0
  CAM 3
  WERS N.A.
  DVDE 3
  ```
- File output "output_UPS.txt"

  ```
  AMFR 0
  AMFR 0
  AMFR 0
  ANAPC11 2
  CRB 2
  CRB 2
  TER 0
  CAM 3
  DVDE 3
  ```

In a similar setting using files organized differently I tried the following under the advice of a friend:

```bsh
for name in ????_?
do
   for file in $name/Pocket_???_$name\.pdb_OUTPUT.txt
   do
      grep -H Exposed $file | uniq
   done
done
```

However I can not adjust that to my current case. The operating system is a CentOS 7.

Are there someone that could help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you show us what you already tried, so that we may see what tools are at your disposal? Also, please add OS flavor and version, as the necessary syntax sometimes depends on that ...

Comment: I’m just approaching the programming schedule and I still can’t do much more but this step is quite urgent and I don't know how I can do this. However I did a similar operation using files organized differently under the advice of a friend. But now I’m elewhere and I have to manage on my own, but as I said it’s quite urgent. the code that I used I was this: for name in ????_?; do for file in $name/Pocket_???_$name\.pdb_OUTPUT.txt; do grep -H Exposed $file | uniq; done; done
However I can not readjust it to my current case. The operating system is a centos7

Answer (score 3):

As long as `awk` is a valid alternative to `grep`, the following should work:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2} NR>FNR{print $1,a[$1]}' UPS.txt all_E3.txt > output_UPS.txt
```

- This will first read `UPS.txt` and create a map `a` between the first and second column.
- When processing reaches the next file `all_E3.txt` (indicated by `NR`, the global line-counter being different from `FNR`, the per-file line-counter), it will output the "first column" of that file and the associated value from the map created earlier in the second column.

The output will be redirected to `output_UPS.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for your rapidly answer but unfortunately the output file has only the name of the objects and there aren't any variable associated.

Comment: @Tommaso Was any of these files created under Windows? If so, run `dos2unix` on them first.

Comment: yes! Now works well! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! If you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) so that others facing a similar problem may find it more easily.